# Determining the Current Scroll Location objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to get the amount of scroll that has been scrolled in the screen.

I've been searching and I didnt find anything, this can be done, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
```

`offset.y` - is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The `contentOffset` property of your `UIScrollView` returns the amount of scroll. Its `x` component tells you how much has been scrolled horizontally; `y` tells you how much has been scrolled vertically.